# How to create a query that retrieve data from several tables, and there is no relationship between the tables

Tags: php, mysql

As described in the title.

How to create a query that retrieve data from several tables, and there is no relationship between the tables.

**Example:**
I have two table like the following:

```
Table (Categories)          Table (Pic_files)
-------------------  |  ---------------------- 
 Cat_id | cat_name   |   pic_id  | pic_title 
-------------------  |  ----------------------
   1    |  Animals   |      1    | Dog_Walks
-------------------  |  ----------------------
   2    |  Nature    |      2    | red_flower
------------------   |  ----------------------
                     |      3    | blue_flower
                     |  ----------------------
 so on  |  so on     |    so on  |   so on
------------------   |  ----------------------
```

What I want is like the next two queries combined in one query

**Query 1:**

```
("SELECT cat_name FROM Categories WHERE Cat_id='2'")
```

**Query 2:**

```
("SELECT pic_title FROM Pic_files WHERE Cat_id='2' LIMIT 5 ")
```

And if I wanted print out data of specific table I doing the next

```
foreach($data as $pic){
  echo $pic['pic_title']; // to get the data from Categories table
}
```

also if that

```
foreach($data as $cat){
  echo $cat['cat_name']; // to get the data from Pic_files table
}
```

**In short, I want to combine 2 or more queries in one query, and treating with them by column name, and don't forget that all tables doesn't have any relationship to some**

Comment: Strange that in your example there IS a relationship between the tables (Cat_ID).  So of course it is easy to do a `JOIN` on those tables.  But I guess I don't know what you mean about trying to JOIN unrelated tables. Can you give an example?

Comment: yes, there are relationship but that is just an example, but I want treating with them without relationship.

Comment: I want to make 2 queries in one to reduce the number of queries in my script

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a cross join:

```
select *
from (SELECT cat_name FROM Categories WHERE Cat_id='2') cat cross join
     (SELECT pic_title FROM Pic_files WHERE Cat_id='2' LIMIT 5) t
```

Comment: Very good, but there is a problem. when there is no data from any table gives me an error. I want to if there is no data in any table, complements the the query to get the data from other tables.

Answer (score 0):

I think what folks are struggling with here in giving you an answer is understanding what you are looking for.

There are certainly PHP libraries which will allow you to execute multiple SQL queries with a single call to the database. See mysqli_multi_query as an example. But, it doesn't sound like this is what you are looking for.  It seems you want to find a magical way to execute multiple queries on unrelated tables as a single query and then somehow magically be able to get at the sets of data independently.  If you are going to do things like Cartesian joins on unrelated tables, you are going to end up with orders of magnitude greater results in your result set than what you are looking for, introducing performance problems on both the database and the application.

It sounds like you want to reduce the number of queries for the sake of reducing the number of queries, which sounds like a bad design approach IMO.  Certainly you can minimize queries on RELATED tables using joins. But to try to somehow JOIN unrelated tables will probably introduce more complexity and performance problems into your system than you are bargaining for. Reducing queries on the database is not the end all be all of database performance optimization.  You need to make sure you have tables properly indexed for your queries. You need to make sure you have appropriate data types and sizes for the data you are storing.  You need to make sure you have a properly allocated memory to keep your indexes in memory. You need to make sure you have a properly configured server to meet your memory, disk capacity, and disk I/O requirements.  Once you have all that maximally optimized, and your system is maxed out, and you have determined that the problem on your system is having two different queries to unrelated tables instead of one combined query, then you should worry about what you are worrying about now.